# Focus IE window in powershell

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, powershell, windows-8, taskbar

My code:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("http://localhost")
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.fullscreen = $true
```

However, after fullscreen, the window still appears *behind* the Windows taskbar. When I click the window to give it focus, the taskbar falls behind and it appears how I want it to. How can I do this programmatically? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This was a toughy... Not as simple as I thought.

I ended up using a cheat and adding the VB assembly:

```
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.VisualBasic"

$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("http://localhost")
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.fullscreen = $true
While ($ie.Busy) { Sleep -m 10 }
$ieProc = Get-Process | ? { $_.MainWindowHandle -eq $ie.HWND }
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($ieProc.Id)
```

Comment: $ie does not have focus method, $ie.document does, so $ie.document.focus() would be the correct statement, however that does not bring it up to the front, at least on Windows 8.1. You just see IE blink on the taskbar...

Comment: Thanks Adil. Not as straight forward as I thought.

Comment: Yeah, I saw people using AppActivate of VB or creating a shell and using that as a wrapper for this. I wish there was an easier way to do it directly with PowerShell. You could btw have also done: get-process iexplore and then filter