# Powershell SendKeys F5 sent to wrong Tab in IE

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, scripting

I want to make a Script which opens IE with 4 tabs, goes to fullscreen and then switches between the tabs while constantly reloading the pages as soon as they get opened.

```
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms     
$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"  
$ie.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com")
$ie.Navigate2("http://www.google.com" , 2048)
$ie.Navigate2("http://www.outlook.com" , 2048)
$ie.Navigate2("http://www.vice.com" , 2048)
$ie.Visible = $true
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F11}{ENTER}")

do
{
start-sleep -Milliseconds 4000
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F5}{ENTER}")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^{TAB}')
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F5}{ENTER}")
}
While ($i -ne 0)
```

With this current script, the browser and the tabs open and it also switches between tabs. The Problem is, for example, if it switches to google, microsoft gets refreshed instead of google.

The other problem is, that it doesn't go in to fullscreen. Is the command in the wrong place?

PS: This is my first PS Script

Comment: Why do you send  `{ENTER}` after `{F11}` and `{F5}`?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I don't know. I copied everything... I'll try without the ENTER

Comment: Not saying this solves your problem, but what happens if you do this manually?

Comment: It doesn't change anything

Comment: So the `{ENTER}` was superfluous :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried the following, but from looking at your code, there are a few things strange:

1. There's no pause between showing the IE window and trying to make it fullscreen. I'd add that.
2. You're sending `{ENTER}` for no reason.
3. In your loop you first refresh the current tab, then switch tabs, then refresh the new tab. Why?

I'd change the code as follows:

```
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms     
$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"  
$ie.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com")
$ie.Navigate2("http://www.google.com" , 2048)
$ie.Navigate2("http://www.outlook.com" , 2048)
$ie.Navigate2("http://www.vice.com" , 2048)
$ie.Visible = $true

start-sleep -Milliseconds 1000
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F11}")

do
{
    start-sleep -Milliseconds 4000
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^{TAB}')
    start-sleep -Milliseconds 100
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F5}")
}
While ($i -ne 0)
```

Comment: As I said, this is my first script so I have no idea what could be wrong or anything. Thanks for correcting it. The refreshing works now. But it still doesn't go into fullscreen. Furthermore I have to click into the IE after I run the script. Is there a way that the script automatically knows that it has to run in the IE window which it just opened?

Comment: Hm. Maybe this question/answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282919/focus-ie-window-in-powershell. Also you could check the COM-Interface and find out whether all that `SendWait` stuff could be replaced by method calls. And there are also events, for example when the page has finished loading. This could improve your overall performance. Documentation is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx